# Problem with NSMutableArray and valueforkey

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, nsmutablearray, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I use a plist file to get a list of site which are displayed in a tableview

The plist looks like this:

```
   <array>
        <dict>
            <key>site</key>
            <string>http://yahoo.com</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>Yahoo</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>site</key>
            <string>http://google.com</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>Google</string>
        </dict>
//...etc
    </array>
    </plist>
```

I display this without problem:

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestData" ofType:@"plist"]];  
        [self setContentsList:array];
```

****The problem is when I try to search in the content and I want to get the valueforkey @"site" from the search result to use it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: ****

```
    NSMutableArray *contentsList;   
    NSMutableArray *searchResults;
    NSString *savedSearchTerm;
---------------------
- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{


    [self setSavedSearchTerm:searchTerm];

    if ([self searchResults] == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self setSearchResults:array];
        [array release], array = nil;
    }

    [[self searchResults] removeAllObjects];

    if ([[self savedSearchTerm] length] != 0)
    {
        for (NSString *currentString in [[self contentsList] valueForKey:@"title"])
        {
            if ([currentString rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [[self searchResults] addObject:currentString];
               // NSDictionary *dic= [[NSDictionary alloc]allKeysForObject:searchResults];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The didSelectRowAtIndexPath is used to open the site in a webView

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    NSString *arraySite = [[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"site"];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arraySite]]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showSearch:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

}
```

ERROR I GET :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSCFString 0x6042730> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key site.'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The Basics

When you read the array from that plist, the array looks like the following:

```
(
    {
        "site"  = "http://yahoo.com",
        "title" = "Yahoo"
    },

    {
        "site"  = "http://google.com",
        "title" = "Google"
    },

    …
)
```

It is an array whose elements are dictionaries, each dictionary containing two keys and their corresponding values.

When you use the KVC method `-valueForKey:` on the array passing the key `title`, it returns another array whose elements are the values corresponding to that key:

```
(
    "Yahoo",
    "Google",
    …
)
```

The resulting array doesn’t hold a reference to the original array.

## The Problem

In `-handleSearchForTerm:`, you get an array containing only the titles from the original array. For each title, you selectively add it to the `searchResults` array:

```
for (NSString *currentString in [[self contentsList] valueForKey:@"title"])
{
    …
    [[self searchResults] addObject:currentString];
}
```

This means that `searchResults` is an array containing a list of titles which are not automatically related to the corresponding dictionaries in the `contentList` array.

It seems like you want to keep the original dictionary because you’ve tried to create a dictionary:

```
// NSDictionary *dic= [[NSDictionary alloc]allKeysForObject:searchResults];
```

and, in another method, you’re trying to obtain the value corresponding to the `site` key:

```
NSString *arraySite = [[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
    valueForKey:@"site"];
```

As mentioned, your `searchResults` contains a list of strings representing titles. When you obtain an element from this array, it’s only a string — hence `-valueForKey:@"site"` doesn’t make sense, and Cocoa warns you that a string is not key-value compliant for the key `site`.

## One Solution

From what I can tell, you should be storing, in your `searchResults` array, the original dictionary read from the plist file. In `-handleSearchForTerm:`, do the following:

```
for (NSDictionary *currentSite in [self contentsList])
{
    NSString *title = [currentSite objectForKey:@"title"];
    if ([title rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [[self searchResults] addObject:currentSite];
    }
}
```

Now every element in `searchResults` is a dictionary containing both `site` and `title`.

In `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, use the dictionary to obtain the corresponding `site`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *selectedSite = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *siteStringURL = [selectedSite objectForKey:@"site"];
    // or, if you prefer everything in a single line:
    // NSString *siteStringURL = [[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"site"];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:siteStringURL]]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showSearch:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```